# visual graph representation in gui

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graph

So I am working on this project for class and the assignment was to build a digraph in java and have it resemble all of the courses in the CS department. With the course prerequisites edges leading into the courses that have the other course as a prerec. I did the assignment I just want to take it farther for my own knowledge and want to make a gui representation of the graph. I also want it to be able to handle different kinds of course inputs not just the ones from the CS department. So the problem I am running into is generating **X** amount of buttons to represent the courses. I can make it with a fixed number I am just not sure how I would do it with a **X** amount. Any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explore doing it yourself, you can combine `GraphPanel`, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11944233/230513), with `PointyThing`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15607737/230513). Alternatively, look at one of the graph libraries mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15702152/230513).